# imagem background no div

Tags: angular-6

Não mostra a imagem

```
<div style="background-image:url(http://localhost:4200/assets/images/background/login-register.jpg);"></div>
```

Digitando assim no browser, http://localhost:4200/assets/images/background/login-register.jpg, mostra a imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código html

> ```
> <div style="background-image:url(assets/images/background/login-register.jpg);">
>   <div class="login-register-box">
>     <mat-card>
>       <mat-card-content>
>         <form [formGroup]="formularioLogin">
>           <div class="text-center"><img alt="homepage" src="assets/images/logo-icon.png">
>             <h4 class="m-t-0">{{ 'LOGIN_PAGINA.SISTEMA' | translate }}</h4>
>           </div>
>           <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutWrap="wrap">
>             <div fxFlex.gt-sm="100" fxFlex.gt-xs="100" fxFlex="100">
>               <mat-form-field>
>                 <input matInput placeholder="{{ 'LOGIN_PAGINA.DOCUMENTO' | translate }}" required
>                   matTooltip="{{ 'LOGIN_PAGINA.DOCUMENTO' | translate }}" id="login" formControlName="login"
>                   name="login">
>               </mat-form-field>
>             </div>
>             <div fxFlex.gt-sm="100" fxFlex.gt-xs="100" fxFlex="100">
>               <mat-form-field>
>                 <input matInput type="password" placeholder="{{ 'LOGIN_PAGINA.SENHA' | translate }}" required
>                   matTooltip="{{ 'LOGIN_PAGINA.SENHA' | translate }}" id="senha" formControlName="senha" name="senha"
>                   [type]="hide ? 'text' : 'password'">
>                 <mat-icon matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide">{{hide ? 'visibility' : 'visibility_off'}}</mat-icon>
>               </mat-form-field>
>             </div>
>             <div fxFlex.gt-sm="100" fxFlex.gt-xs="100" fxFlex="100">
>               <button mat-raised-button color="primary" class="btn-block btn-lg m-t-20 m-b-20" type="button"
>                 [disabled]="loading" (click)="logar()">{{ 'LOGIN' | translate }}
>               </button> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
>               <button mat-raised-button color="primary" class="btn-block btn-lg m-t-20 m-b-20" type="button"
>                 [disabled]="loading" (click)="alterarSenha()">{{ 'LOGIN_PAGINA.ALTERAR_SENHA' | translate }}
>               </button>
>             </div>
>           </div>
>         </form>
>       </mat-card-content>
>     </mat-card>
>   </div>
> </div>
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Acontece que a sua `div` não tem tamanho, então a imagem não aparece!

Coloque assim: `style="width: 500px; height: 500px; background-image: url(/assets/images/background/login-register.jpg)"`

Agora ele tem um tamanho e pega a imagem direto da raíz

Comment: Valeu. Coloquei assim <div tyle="width: 500px; height: 500px; background-image:url(/assets/images/background/login-register.jpg);"> e não funcionou da mesma maneira

Comment: Faz igual está na resposta, é apenas um style.

Assim: `style="width: 500px; height: 500px; background-image: url(/assets/images/background/login-register.jpg)"`

Comment: Vi que está escrito `tyle`, você colocou corretamente no código?

Comment: Coloquei assim <div style="width: 500px; height: 500px; background-image: url(/assets/images/background/login-register.jpg)">, mas não funcionou

@Lucas Bittencourt, erro de digitação

Comment: Usa a URL q vc tinha colocado antes: `http://localhost:4200/assets/images/background/login-register.jpg`

Comment: Funcionou.

Mas como fazer para pegar a página toda e os componentes em cima ?

Não ficou como imaginava

Comment: Faz isso: style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100vh; background-image: url(http://localhost:4200/assets/images/background/login-register.jpg)"

Comment: Resolvido. 

Obrigado

Como coloco este post como resolvido ?

Comment: É só clicar no botãozinho e deixar verde, como você fez :)